# Black voodoo of NumPy Einsum

Tags: python, numpy

I got some working code using einsum function. But as einsum is currently still like `black voodoo` for me. I was wondering, what this code actually is doing and if it can be somehow optimized using `np.dot`

My data looks likes this

```
n, p, q = 40000, 8, 4
a = np.random.rand(n, p, q)
b = np.random.rand(n, p)
```

And my existing functions einsum functions looks like this

```
f1 = np.einsum("ijx,ijy->ixy", a, a)
f2 = np.einsum("ijx,ij->ix", a, b)
```

But what does it really do? I get till here: each dimension (axis) is represented by a label, `i` is equal to the first axis `n`, `j` for the 2nd axis `p` and `x` and `y` are different labels for the same axis `q`.
So the order of the output array of `f1` is `ixy` and thus the output shape is `40000,4,4 (n,q,q)`

But that's as far as I get. And

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) should help you understand what `einsum` does!

Comment: @Phillip Thanks for the link! That defintely helped. But also made me realise more that I am not able to optimise this by myself as this goes above my head..

Comment: Often `einsum` is as good as `dot`.  Both are compiled.  `dot` just has tighter code for a specific combination of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets play around with a couple of small arrays

```
In [110]: a=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)

In [111]: b=np.arange(2*3).reshape(2,3)

In [112]: np.einsum('ijx,ij->ix',a,b)
Out[112]: 
array([[ 20,  23,  26,  29],
       [200, 212, 224, 236]])

In [113]: np.diagonal(np.dot(b,a)).T
Out[113]: 
array([[ 20,  23,  26,  29],
       [200, 212, 224, 236]])
```

`np.dot` operates on the last dim of the 1st array, and 2nd to the last of the 2nd.  So I have to switch the arguments so the `3` dimension lines up.  `dot(b,a)` produces a (2,2,4) array.  `diagonal` selects 2 of those 'rows', and transpose to clean up.  Another `einsum` expresses that cleanup nicely:

```
In [122]: np.einsum('iik->ik',np.dot(b,a))
```

Since `np.dot` is producing a larger array than the original `einsum`, it is unlikely to be faster, even if the underlying C code is tighter.

(Curiously I'm having trouble replicating `np.dot(b,a)` with `einsum`; it won't generate that (2,2,...) array).

For the `a,a` case we have to do something similar - roll the axes of one array so the last dimension lines up with the 2nd to last of the other, do the `dot`, and then cleanup with `diagonal` and `transpose`:

```
In [157]: np.einsum('ijx,ijy->ixy',a,a).shape
Out[157]: (2, 4, 4)
In [158]: np.einsum('ijjx->jix',np.dot(np.rollaxis(a,2),a))
In [176]: np.diagonal(np.dot(np.rollaxis(a,2),a),0,2).T
```

`tensordot` is another way of taking a `dot` over selected axes.

```
np.tensordot(a,a,(1,1))
np.diagonal(np.rollaxis(np.tensordot(a,a,(1,1)),1),0,2).T  # with cleanup
```

Comment: that was a great explanation! Realise that `einsum` is really powerful and in fact much more 'readable' by knowing now what it is doing.

Comment: As for your remark, `np.einsum('ij,kjl', b, a) == np.dot(b, a)`.